# Conversion pinescript function with nested queries

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

How can this function be converted from version 4 to 5. My attempts are all acknowledged with errors. The problem is the nesting of the Iff statement. It's not clear to me how the if nesting is done here and how to convert it to Pinescript 5?

Here the Version 4:

```
__p() =>
     _p = 0
    if usePeriods and not timeframe.isseconds
        _p := iff(timeframe.isminutes,
                 iff(timeframe.period ==   '1', _db(_p1mD),
                 iff(timeframe.period ==   '3' or timeframe.period == '5', _db(_p3mD),
                 iff(timeframe.period ==  '10', _db(_p10mD),
                 iff(timeframe.period ==  '15', _wb(_p15mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period ==  '30', _wb(_p30mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period ==  '60', _wb(_p60mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period == '120', _wb(_p120mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period == '180', _wb(_p180mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '195', _wb(_p240mW),
                 iff(timeframe.period == '360', _wb(_p360mW),
                 _wb(4))))))))))),
             iff(timeframe.period == 'D', _wb(_pD),
             iff(timeframe.period == 'W', _pW,
             iff(timeframe.period == 'M', _pM,
             _db(10)))))
    else
        _p := _bars
    _p := bar_index - 1 < _p ? bar_index - 1 : _p
    _p < 2 ? 2 : _p                       

var int _p = na
_p := __p()
```

Here my conversion Version 5 with erros:

```
__p() =>
     _p = 0

     if usePeriods and not timeframe.isseconds
           _p := timeframe.isminutes ?
                timeframe.period ==   '1' ? _db(_p1mD) :
                timeframe.period ==   '3' or timeframe.period == '5' ? _db(_p3mD) :
                timeframe.period ==  '10' ? _db(_p10mD) :
                timeframe.period ==  '15' ? _wb(_p15mW) :
                timeframe.period ==  '30' ? _wb(_p30mW) :
                timeframe.period ==  '60' ? _wb(_p60mW) :
                timeframe.period == '120' ? _wb(_p120mW) :
                timeframe.period == '180' ? _wb(_p180mW) :
                timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '195' ? _wb(_p240mW) :
                timeframe.period == '360' ? _wb(_p360mW) :_wb(4) :
                timeframe.period == 'D' ? _wb(_pD) :
                timeframe.period == 'W' ? _pW :
                timeframe.period == 'M' ? _pM : _db(10)

    else
        _p := _bars
    _p := bar_index - 1 < _p ? bar_index - 1 : _p
    _p < 2 ? 2 : _p   

var int _p = na
_p := __p()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the converter tool to upgrade your script from v3+.

This is how it converts:

```
__p() =>
    _p = 0
    if usePeriods and not timeframe.isseconds
        _db_1 = _db(_p1mD)
        _db_2 = _db(_p3mD)
        _db_3 = _db(_p10mD)
        _db_4 = _db(_p15mW)
        _db_5 = _db(_p30mW)
        _db_6 = _db(_p60mW)
        _db_7 = _db(_p120mW)
        _db_8 = _db(_p180mW)
        _db_9 = _db(_p240mW)
        _db_10 = _db(_p360mW)
        _db_11 = _db(4)
        iff_1 = timeframe.period == '360' ? _db_10 : _db_11
        iff_2 = timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '195' ? _db_9 : iff_1
        iff_3 = timeframe.period == '180' ? _db_8 : iff_2
        iff_4 = timeframe.period == '120' ? _db_7 : iff_3
        iff_5 = timeframe.period == '60' ? _db_6 : iff_4
        iff_6 = timeframe.period == '30' ? _db_5 : iff_5
        iff_7 = timeframe.period == '15' ? _db_4 : iff_6
        iff_8 = timeframe.period == '10' ? _db_3 : iff_7
        iff_9 = timeframe.period == '3' or timeframe.period == '5' ? _db_2 : iff_8
        iff_10 = timeframe.period == '1' ? _db_1 : iff_9
        _db_12 = _db(_pD)
        _db_13 = _db(10)
        iff_11 = timeframe.period == 'M' ? _pM : _db_13
        iff_12 = timeframe.period == 'W' ? _pW : iff_11
        iff_13 = timeframe.period == 'D' ? _db_12 : iff_12
        _p := timeframe.isminutes ? iff_10 : iff_13
        _p
    else
        _p := _bars
        _p
    _p := bar_index - 1 < _p ? bar_index - 1 : _p
    _p < 2 ? 2 : _p
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be like:

```
__p() =>
    _p = 0

    if usePeriods and not timeframe.isseconds
        if timeframe.isminutes
            _p := timeframe.period == '1' ? _db(_p1mD) :
                 timeframe.period == '3' or timeframe.period == '5' ? _db(_p3mD) :
                 timeframe.period == '10' ? _db(_p10mD) :
                 timeframe.period == '15' ? _wb(_p15mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '30' ? _wb(_p30mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '60' ? _wb(_p60mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '120' ? _wb(_p120mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '180' ? _wb(_p180mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '240' or timeframe.period == '195' ? _wb(_p240mW) :
                 timeframe.period == '360' ? _wb(_p360mW) :
                 _wb(4)
        else
            _p := timeframe.period == 'D' ? _wb(_pD) :
                 timeframe.period == 'W' ? _pW :
                 timeframe.period == 'M' ? _pM :
                 _db(10)

    else
        _p := _bars
    _p := bar_index - 1 < _p ? bar_index - 1 : _p
    _p < 2 ? 2 : _p   

var int _p = na
_p := __p()
```

For better readability, you may consider using [switch](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_switch) instead of [ternary operators](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator).